# Retrieving all sequentially created znodes with curator

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

If I create zookeeper znodes using CreateMode.PERSISTENT_SEQUENTIAL for a set PATH.

```
String PATH = "/Configuration";

rawLocation = zk.create()
.withMode(CreateMode.PERSISTENT_SEQUENTIAL)
.forPath(PATH, data.getBytes());
```

Is is possible to retrieve all the sequentially named zNodes created using just the PATH?

The CreateMode.PERSISTENT_SEQUENTIAL option in the .withMode method creates a zNode referenced by PATH appended by a 10 digit incremental number. 
The documentation refers to the PATH as the Parent path. But I can not seem to use the getData or checkExists() method on a zNode referenced by the PATH itself. 
In other words I want to use PATH as a parent and use getChildren() method to get the sequentially generated nodes. Is this possible?

I found/realised the solution. If I ended the PATH variable with a "/" and added .creatingParentsIfNeeded() to the create method chain, it created the needed parental zNode.

```
String PATH = "/Configurations/"
```

Comment: You mean something like `ls PATH` in console ?

Comment: No, The PATH variable in the forPath(PATH, data.getBytes) method.

Comment: I mean, programmatically. something like. zk.getChildren().forPath(PATH)